# Fetch Google Default account in case of multiaccount session

Tags: javascript, php, google-api, google-authentication

Is it possible to fetch default Google account?

I checked the documentation around [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/php) and [JS client-side auth](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in). As result I didn't find any functional like fetch default account in case of multi account Google account session.

Screenshot of window to understood:

[image]

Comment: What you need to do is send the login hint with the request if you know the users email that you want them to login with.    How you do that in javascript im not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your attention to my question. Yes, I already used it. But when I try to force the user to use the right account by comparing the right email and JS client-side auth with login hint email, after with redirect to Google Meet Session they open it with the default account and that's a point. I work with sometimes non-engineer senior users and it will be very helpful to force the default account in the login process. Maybe it possible somehow.